# Instead of String how to handle Large String value without loss of data?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming my issue is requesting web `webservice` and then receive the response.The response field is very large when i convert it to `byte[]` and then `Bitmap` it shows error like value not completely received from webservice. Can anyone help me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: PLease post the Code that you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
String result = response.getProperty(0).toString();
```

Use this code.